# is there a way to repeat this loop function with some modification?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, repeat

i'm beginner and I would like to know if there is some way to repeat this function but in each time it should replace the alphabet depending on the while condition;
here is the code:

```
NUM=input("Please enter the number: "+
  ' (Or enter nothing to stop.):')
while ds.index(NUM)<300:
    if ds.index(NUM)<60:
        print("A","0","1level",(ds.index(NUM)))
        break
    elif ds.index(NUM)<120:
        print("A","O","2level",(ds.index(NUM)))
        break
    elif ds.index(NUM)< 180:
        print("A","0","3level",(ds.index(NUM)))
        break
    elif ds.index(NUM)<240:
        print("A","O","4level",(ds.index(NUM)))
        break
    elif ds.index(NUM)<300:
        print("A","O","5level",(ds.index(NUM)))
        break
```

what i want is :
when ds.index(NUM)<600: to repeat the function but to replace "A" by "B"
and  when  ds.index(NUM)<900: ater  repeatting the  function replace "A" by "C"and so on
thank you

Comment: Kindly [edit] the post and properly format the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for input inside the loop, otherwise `NUM` never changes.

```
while True:
    NUM=input("Please enter the number: "+
        ' (Or enter nothing to stop.):')
    if NUM == '':
        break
    elif ds.index(NUM)<60:
        print("A","0","1level",(ds.index(NUM)))
        break
    elif ds.index(NUM)<120:
        print("A","O","2level",(ds.index(NUM)))
        break
    elif ds.index(NUM)< 180:
        print("A","0","3level",(ds.index(NUM)))
        break
    elif ds.index(NUM)<240:
        print("A","O","4level",(ds.index(NUM)))
        break
    elif ds.index(NUM)<300:
        print("A","O","5level",(ds.index(NUM)))
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid number, try again")
```

Comment: yes you right, thanks for answering, do u have any idea how can i  repeat the function but to replace "A" by "B"   when ds.index(NUM)<600 and when ds.index(NUM)<900: replace "A" by "C" and so on ? thank you